# When does Android actually perform Backup

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I am using Android `BackupManager` to backup my application data. But as it is stated in the documentation that Android perform lazy backup as it doesnot perform it as soon as I call its `dataChanged()` method but waits for appropriate time.. I just want to know is there any flag set or something noticeable happens when it does perform backup on cloud..